# python print isn't work during the for loop

Tags: python, time, while-loop

I want to check a some value in the python 2.7 during the for loop. And I want to print a current time. The problem is print isn't operate during the for loop. When the for loop finished, the print is operated. My Source code is below.

[ Code ]

```
import time

def display():
    print "Something..."

while(1):
    time.sleep(1)
    display()
```

Who know the reason? or solution?

Comment: This will print once a second. After the screen fills it may appear to stop but really it's just scrolling. So, what do you observe?

Comment: "Not working" is not a detailed enough description of the problem to enable us to help you.

Comment: Try running it directly from the shell/command-line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import time

def display(something):
    print something

index = 1
while(1):
    time.sleep(1)
    display(index)
    index += 1
```